# How can I get two page aligned(0x1000) and separated program headers?

Tags: linux, linker-scripts, dep

I am trying to implement custom loader and

want to locate two program headers(segment) for data and code with 0x1000 aligned.

I fixed some part of the default linker script and get weird results.

```
**Default linker script.**
. = ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) - ((CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - .) & 
(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1));
. = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT(MAXPAGESIZE),CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));

**Modified linker script**
. = ALIGN (0x1000);
. = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN(0x1000, 0x1000);
```

when I compiled the binary with default linker script, it is 0x200000 aligned

and have two program headers.

```
LOAD         0x0000000000000000 0x0000000050000000 0x0000000050000000
             0x0000000000001058 0x0000000000001058  R E    200000
LOAD         0x0000000000001fe8 0x0000000050201fe8 0x0000000050201fe8
             0x0000000000000028 0x00000000000000c0  RW     200000
```

but I get below result with modified linker script.

```
LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000050000000 0x0000000050000000
               0x0000000000002010 0x00000000000020a8  RWE    200000
```

It seems that the data section and code section is mixed in one program header.

However, I want to make my program have two page aligned(0x1000) program headers

```
LOAD1        0x0000000050000000 ~ 0x0000000050002340 R E
LOAD2        0x0000000050003000 ~ 0x0000000050006790 RW
```

Please let me know some directions.

Comment: I haven't dealt much with linker scripts, but I expect the script does more than just set `.`. Is this snippet between the section declarations? Could you add more of the surrounding script?

Comment: By default, ld linker script locates two segment with 0x200000 alignment (one for code(RX) and one for data(RW)), but what I want is locating two segment back to back. Briefly speaking, I don't want to make some space between two segment because I don't want to waste my memory pages. This is x64 binary and data is referenced using the offset, So I want my linker script locate these two segments back to back. Thanks

Comment: I found the answer about this question. Please look at this URL
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005638/how-to-change-alignment-of-code-segment-in-elf

Comment: Try linking with the option `-z max-page-size=0x1000` which changes the default ma page size from 2mb to 4mb.